# Kenmore 500 Series Dryer Petroleum Smell

Tags: dryer

I have a Kenmore 500 Series electric dryer. Model number 110.67542600.

It produces an oil like smell that all the clothes pick up. Even when run at its minimum temperature.

Is this s common issue with these units? Which part(s) are likely to cause it or what should I check on first?

[This](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/59592/what-could-have-caused-the-burnt-electronics-smell-in-my-kenmore-washer-and-drye) question seems similar except the description of the smell doesn't match. Mine is not an "ozone" smell but a petroleum one.

Comment: Is this a new dryer?

Comment: There should be very little oil in a dryer, maybe a bit of grease/oil to lubricate motor bearings, but they are usually sealed.  Any chance some oil on clothes got in there?  Any chance the smell is plastic melting/burning instead of petroleum?